# Log in anonymously to firebase authentication and add onCompleteListener when user rotates his/her while the authentication is in progress?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm making random chat app where every 2 users are in 1 room. My app worked well if I don't rotate the device, but I just tried to rotate several times right after app is launched to make app robust. Then, the app crashed right away

**how can I log in anonymously to firebase authentication and add onCompleteListener when user rotates his/her while the firebase authentication is in progress?**

When I first launch the app, a `dialog` is showed up which is used to announce the user that the app is initializing something and during the `dialog` is showed in `onCreateView` of a `fragment`, app tries to log in to `firebase authentication` anonymously and set `onCompleteListener` because when `authentication` is completed,

I have to insert to `firebase database` `'/user_state/{uid}/"home"'` with uid and dismiss `dialog` to make user possible to push button which is used to find another user to chat where the uid is needed too.

Because the uid is needed in both jobs, I need to do these jobs right after the `authentication` is completed.

I just thought that I could implement inserting `'/user_state/{uid}/"home"'` by cloud functions for `firebase`, but I didn't know how I could know the time when I dismiss the initializing `dialog` that I showed before because I have to know when the `authentication` is completed and I need callback function. So I added `onCompleteListener` like this

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:success");
                        mAuthInitDialog.dismiss();
                        mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        UserState state = new UserState(STATE_HOME);
                        mFirebaseDatabase
                                .getReference("user_state/" + mCurrentUser.getUid())
                                .setValue(state);

                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());
                        mAuthInitDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

But when I rotate the device, the `activity` is `destroyed` and `listener` has gone for sure. So, I just thought that how about changing my code like below

```
Task mTask = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously();
mTask.addOnCompleteListener( ...
```

and I used `onSaveInstanceState` method and `Gson` to save my `Task Object` like below

```
bundle.putString(BUNDLE_TASK_AUTH, new Gson().toJson(mTaskAuth));
```

and restored like below

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
    mTask =  new Gson().fromJson(savedInstanceState.getString(BUNDLE_TASK_AUTH), Task.class);
    mTask.setOnCompleteListener( ...
}
```

But, I'm not sure if the listener could catch the authentication complete event even though the listener is retored after the fragment is recreated every time

Because I thought that authentication complete event can occur when after the activity is destroyed and before the activity is recreated.

I just want to make robust app even though there are several device rotations using `firebase authentication`. What should I do?

Code for MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "sgc109.MainFragment";
    private static final String DIALOG_PROGRESS = "DialogProgress";
    private static final String BUNDLE_IS_WAITING = "bundle_is_waiting";
    private static final String BUNDLE_TASK_AUTH = "bundle_task_auth";
    private static final String CMD_START_WAITING = "start_waiting";
    private static final String CMD_STOP_WAITING = "stop_waiting";
    private static final String CMD_EXIT = "exit";
    private static final String CMD_SEND = "send";
    private static final String STATE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String STATE_WAITING = "waiting";
    private static final String STATE_MATCHED = "matched";
    private static final String STATE_PENDING = "pending";



    private static final int REQUEST_CHAT_ROOM = 0;

    private boolean isWaiting;
    private boolean hasRequestedAuth;
    private Task mTaskAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Button mEnterTheRoomButton;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private ProgressDialog mAuthInitDialog;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "retore savedInstanceState!");
            isWaiting = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(BUNDLE_IS_WAITING, false);
            mTaskAuth =  new Gson().fromJson(savedInstanceState.getString(BUNDLE_TASK_AUTH), Task.class);
        }

        if (isWaiting) {
            showProgressDialog();
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        if (mCurrentUser == null) {
            mAuthInitDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            mAuthInitDialog.setTitle("첫 실행 초기화 중");
            mAuthInitDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            mAuthInitDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mAuthInitDialog.show();

            if (mTaskAuth == null) {
                mTaskAuth = mAuth.signInAnonymously();
            }
            mTaskAuth.addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:success");
                        mAuthInitDialog.dismiss();
                        mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        UserState state = new UserState(STATE_HOME);
                        mFirebaseDatabase
                                .getReference("user_state/" + mCurrentUser.getUid())
                                .setValue(state);

                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());
                        mAuthInitDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            mFirebaseDatabase
                    .getReference()
                    .child("user_state")
                    .child(mCurrentUser.getUid())
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            UserState state = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserState.class);
                            if (state.state.equals(STATE_MATCHED)) {
                                enterChatRoom();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled");
                        }
                    });
        }

        mEnterTheRoomButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_enter_the_room_button);
        mEnterTheRoomButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mCurrentUser == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (!isWaiting) {
                    startWaitingForOtherUser();
                    isWaiting = true;
                }
                showProgressDialog();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mProgressDialog != null) mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        if (mAuthInitDialog != null) mAuthInitDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSavedInstaneState()");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(BUNDLE_IS_WAITING, isWaiting);
        outState.putString(BUNDLE_TASK_AUTH, new Gson().toJson(mTaskAuth));
    }

    public void showProgressDialog() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                    isWaiting = false;
                    dialog.cancel();
                    stopWaitingForOtherUser();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle(R.string.find_other_user_progress_dialog_text);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    public void stopWaitingForOtherUser() {
        CommandSender.sendCommand(CMD_STOP_WAITING);
    }

    public void startWaitingForOtherUser() {
        CommandSender.sendCommand(CMD_START_WAITING);
    }

    public void enterChatRoom() {
        isWaiting = false;
        Intent intent = ChatRoomActivity.newIntent(getActivity());
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CHAT_ROOM);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CHAT_ROOM:
                boolean reEnter = data.getBooleanExtra(ChatRoomActivity.EXTRA_RE_ENTER_ROOM, false);
                if (reEnter){
                    showProgressDialog();
                    startWaitingForOtherUser();
                }
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using **ViewModel**. I found from [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) that ViewModel holds our data even though Activity is destroyed because of configuration change such as device rotation.

My changed code is below.

**MainFragment.java**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "sgc109.MainFragment";
    private static final String DIALOG_PROGRESS = "DialogProgress";
    private static final String BUNDLE_IS_WAITING = "bundle_is_waiting";
    private static final String BUNDLE_IS_AUTH_COMPLETE = "bundle_is_auth_complete";
    private static final String CMD_START_WAITING = "start_waiting";
    private static final String CMD_STOP_WAITING = "stop_waiting";
    private static final String CMD_EXIT = "exit";
    private static final String CMD_SEND = "send";
    private static final String STATE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String STATE_WAITING = "waiting";
    private static final String STATE_MATCHED = "matched";
    private static final String STATE_PENDING = "pending";


    private static final int REQUEST_CHAT_ROOM = 0;

    private boolean mIsWaiting;
    private boolean mIsAuthComplete;
    private Button mEnterTheRoomButton;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private ProgressDialog mAuthInitDialog;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "retore savedInstanceState!");
            mIsWaiting = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(BUNDLE_IS_WAITING, false);
            mIsAuthComplete = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(BUNDLE_IS_AUTH_COMPLETE, false);
        }

        if (mIsWaiting) {
            showProgressDialog();
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        if (mIsAuthComplete) {
            showAuthInitDialog();
            MyViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
            model.getTask().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    mAuthInitDialog.dismiss();
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:success");
                        mIsAuthComplete = true;
                        UserState state = new UserState(STATE_HOME);
                        FirebaseDatabase
                                .getInstance()
                                .getReference("user_state/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                .setValue(state);

                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            FirebaseDatabase
                    .getInstance()
                    .getReference()
                    .child("user_state")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            UserState state = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserState.class);
                            if (state.state.equals(STATE_MATCHED)) {
                                enterChatRoom();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled");
                        }
                    });
        }

        mEnterTheRoomButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_enter_the_room_button);
        mEnterTheRoomButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Shit Fuck!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                showProgressDialog();
                startWaitingForOtherUser();
                mIsWaiting = true;
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void showAuthInitDialog() {
        mAuthInitDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mAuthInitDialog.setTitle("첫 실행 초기화 중");
        mAuthInitDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mAuthInitDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mAuthInitDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mProgressDialog != null) mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        if (mAuthInitDialog != null) mAuthInitDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSavedInstaneState()");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(BUNDLE_IS_WAITING, mIsWaiting);
        outState.putBoolean(BUNDLE_IS_AUTH_COMPLETE, mIsAuthComplete);
    }

    public void showProgressDialog() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                    mIsWaiting = false;
                    dialog.cancel();
                    stopWaitingForOtherUser();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle(R.string.find_other_user_progress_dialog_text);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    public void stopWaitingForOtherUser() {
        CommandSender.sendCommand(CMD_STOP_WAITING);
    }

    public void startWaitingForOtherUser() {
        CommandSender.sendCommand(CMD_START_WAITING);
    }

    public void enterChatRoom() {
        mIsWaiting = false;
        Intent intent = ChatRoomActivity.newIntent(getActivity());
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CHAT_ROOM);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CHAT_ROOM:
                boolean reEnter = data.getBooleanExtra(ChatRoomActivity.EXTRA_RE_ENTER_ROOM, false);
                if (reEnter) {
                    showProgressDialog();
                    startWaitingForOtherUser();
                }
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

**MyViewModel.java**

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private Task task;
    public Task getTask(){
        if (task == null){
            task = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously();
        }
        return task;
    }
}
```